# SQLite Queryable Interface

Tags: sqlite, uwp

I'm trying to convert to Microsoft.Data.SQLite from System.Data.SQLite but I am having trouble with the following code:

```
Microsoft.Data.SQLite.core
SQLitePCLRaw.bundle_winsqlite3



        List<String> entries = new List<string>();
        using (SqliteConnection db = new SqliteConnection("Filename=VET.db"))
        {
            db.Open();

          var records = db.Table<Templates>().ToList();

            SqliteCommand selectCommand = new SqliteCommand("SELECT TemplateName, TemplateFile from Templates", db);
            SqliteDataReader query = selectCommand.ExecuteReader();
            while (query.Read())
            {
                string tempStr = query[0].ToString() + "," + query[1].ToString();
                templatesCollection.Add(new Templates() { TemplateFile = query[1].ToString(), TemplateName = query[0].ToString() });
            }
            db.Close();
        }
```

>

Basically, I cannot find a queryable table interface.

```
  var list = db.Table<Templates>().ToList();
```

I'm using Nuget and adding Microsoft.Data.Sqlite, am I missing another reference?  Or what else?

Comment: From you code,It looks you used `SQLite.Net-PCL`. For using `Microsoft.Data.Sqlite` please check this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/data-access/sqlite-databases).

Comment: I'm still getting the "SqliteConnection does not contain a definition for "Table" error.  Here are the nuget packages I'm using based on the MSFT documentation. Microsoft.Data.SQLite.core and SQLitePCLRaw.bundle_winsqlite3

Comment: Could you mind share a mini sample that could reproduce the issue ?

Comment: Are there contents in the VET.db database?

Comment: The post example is the one that is failing with the following error msg. Error CS1061 'SqliteConnection' does not contain a definition for 'Table' and no accessible extension method 'Table' accepting a first argument of type 'SqliteConnection' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Nico, Yes, there are records in the db. To be clear, Intellisense throws and error.after typing "db.Table"  It appears the two assemblies do not include the Table<T> method.  I want to convert to the MS.Data.SQlite to save app space and better performance.

Comment: Nico, I have never heard of a "query table"  .  If I use System.Data.Sqlite I can copy the records from the "Templates" table to the var list with the following code "var list = db.Table<Templates>().ToList();" , but if I use Microsoft.Data.Sqlite I still get the error message. Can you show me an example of using xx.Table<T> with the Microsoft Sqlite assembly?

Comment: Does the `Templates` class match with data structure from your database?

Comment: Please don't mix `SQLite.Net-PCL` and  `Microsoft.Data.Sqlite`. They are different way to process database. I have checked your scenario,  `SQLite.Net-PC` is better for you. please refer this [code sample](https://github.com/ZhuMingHao/UWPSqliteTest/tree/master/UWPSqliteTest). For more detail steps please refer this [blog](https://kinani95.wordpress.com/2015/08/05/sqlite-with-uwp/).

Comment: Templates match.  I want to use the Microsoft.Data.SQlite because of this statement from the Microsoft Site.  First off, you can use .NET Standard 2.0 libraries instead of regular class libraries. That means that you can share your data access code with any other .NET-based app such as a WPF, Windows Forms, Android, iOS, or ASP.NET app.
your app does not have package SQLite libraries. your app can use the version of SQLite that comes installed with Windows. This helps you in a few ways.  This is part of this MS doc. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/data-access/sqlite-databases